# How to show the following function is one to one and onto?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, characteristics

I need help with the following question:

Let q be an odd prime power and function f is defined as $f(x)=x^{q+1}$.

Fix an element $a\in F^*_{q^n}$  i.e. $a\neq 0$. Let $D_a$ is defined as follows: $$D_a  : F_{q^n} \rightarrow F_{q^n}$$
                       $$ x\rightarrow f(x+a)-f(x)$$

where  $n\geq 2$

1. Prove that if n is odd then $D_ a$ is 1-1 and onto?
2. What would happen if n is even?

I begin with assuming that $D_a(x)=D_a(y)$ for arbitrary $x$ and $y$ in $F_{q^n}$ and try to see that $x=y$.

I could not see the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $(x+y)^q=x^q+y^q$ you have $(x+a)^{q+1}=(x+a)(x^q+a^q)$ and therefore the difference
$$
L_a(x):=D_a(x)-a^{q+1}=ax^q+a^qx
$$
is an $\Bbb{F}_q$-linear mapping. Therefore the question can be settled by studying the kernel of $L_a$. After all, from linear algebra we recall that a linear transformation is injective if and only if its kernel is trivial.

Let $b\neq0$ be an element of $\mathrm{ker}(L_a)$. Then $ab^q+a^qb=0$, or equivalently $(a/b)^{q-1}=-1.$ This implies that the order of $a/b$ is not a factor of $q-1$, but is a factor of $2(q-1)$. On the other hand, the order of $a/b$ is a factor of $q^n-1$ as that holds for all the elements of $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$.

The parity of $n$ plays a role, because (recall that $q$ was assumed to be odd)
$$
\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}=1+q+q^2+\cdots+q^{n-1}\equiv n\pmod 2.
$$
If $n$ is odd, it follows that $\gcd(2(q-1),q^n-1)=q-1$, proving the non-existence of the above element $b\in\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$, and hence also injectivity of $L_a$ as well as $D_a$. As the domain and codomain have the same finite cardinality, injectivity is equivalent to bijectivity.

On the other hand, if $n$ is even, then $2(q-1)\mid q^n-1$. By cyclicity of the multiplicative group $\Bbb{F}_{q^n}^*$ there exists an element $\gamma\in\Bbb{F}_{q^n}$ of order $2(q-1)$. As $-1$ is the only element of order two, it follows that $\gamma^{q-1}=-1$. Therefore 
$$L_a(a\gamma)=a(a^q\gamma^q)+a^q(a\gamma)=a^{q+1}\gamma(\gamma^{q-1}+1)=0.$$
Hence $D_a(0)=D_a(a\gamma)$, and we have shown that $D_a$ is neither injective not surjective.

Comment: well, i am ashamed to confess that, this is the first time I have heard of $F_q$ linear mapping:(  i think i will read about it. I lack of background in Finite fields. Is it related to linearized polynomials topic? Can you advice me some book or paper that i can read on this  and learn so that i can understand your hint? I have just red the first 3 chapers of Rudolf Lidl Applications of Finite field?

Comment: Yes, it is a linearized polynomial (after we remove the constant $a^{q+1}$ that does not affect surjectivity/injectivity). The topic is studied thoroughly enough in Lidl & Niederreiter, probably elsewhere also.

Comment: I thought about your hint.   When I insert b, I get $L_a(b)=a.b^q+a^q.b=0$ gives me $(a/b)^{q-1}=-1$  from that point if square it I get $(a/b)^{2(q-1)}=1$. Now can we say that the order of (a/b) is 2.(q-1) which is an even number? If we can prove that the kernal of $L_a$ is 0  then we can say that kernal of $D_a$ is also 0 and it is thus 1-1. But  I could not relate it to the order of (a/b) and the even or odd being of n for now :/

Comment: That's a very good start. Well done! More precisely, you can say that the order of $a/b$ is a factor of $2(q-1)$ but that it is not a factor of $q-1$. What does that tell you about $n$? Remember that the order must be a factor of $q^n-1$, and that you know the parity of $(q^n-1)/(q-1)$.

Comment: I think I got what you mean, $q^n−1=(q−1).(1+q+q^2+...+q^n)$ and the order is both a factor of $q^n−1$ and $2.(q−1)$ and we know that the order is definitely not equal to $q−1$, thus the the common factor must not be only $q−1$ alone. It must be $2.(q−1)$ which is even. Thus $(1+q+q^2+...+q^n)$ must have a factor 2 in it. Am I right? Since q values are odd and there are n-many items in the sum, the only choice is n is even.

Comment: So what I get from those is the following:  If the Kernal of $L_a$ is $0$, i.e., $D_a =a^{q+1}$ (nonzero-const. func. since $a$ is nonzero), then, $n$ must  be even.  Am I right here?? And  the contrapositive of this last proposition is: If $n$ is odd then, $D_a$ is  "not constant" (which does not necessarily mean being 1-1) i.e. $ L_a$ is not $1-1$?? But we would like to prove that: If n is odd then $D_a$ is 1-1? We only have  $D_a$ is non-constant in the hand? I am a bit confused with that part:( Confusing part is how can $D_a$ possible be $1-1$, while $L_a $ is being NOT 1-1?

Comment: Correct! If $L_a$ is a bijection(as a function of $x$) so is $D_a$. After all $L_a(x)=L_a(y)$ if and only if $D_a(x)=D_a(y)$.

Comment: but in the question it asks for us to prove if  n is odd, then $D_a$ is bijection, here we have proved  the converse of what is asked. We just proved that when n is odd it is NOT bijection. When n is even it is bijection. So do you think that there might be an error in the question ?? Or may be I am doing something wrong??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102879/discussion-between-esra-and-jyrki-lahtonen).